# swift searching for string in array and return the index

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to search in an array if it contains a string and if it is in the array return the index number where it is located.

I'm new to swift and the only thing I know is how to check if the string contains the string but I have no idea how to get the index from that array.

Yorrick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want index of all the elements from array that contains string you can try like this.

```
let array = ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five"]
let indexArray = array.indices.filter { array[$0].localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("o") }

print(indexArray) // [0, 1, 3]
```